# How can I add a form to edit Comments to each Instance on a Django DetailView?

Tags: django, forms

I am new to Django and trying to figure out how to build a webapp where I have Assets, attached Instances (of these Assets), and Comments attached to these instances, so basically in terms of simplified models.py

```
models.py

class Asset(models.Model)

class Instance(models.Model):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='instances')

class Comment(models.Model):
    instance = models.ForeignKey(Instance, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
```

I know I will have to use forms based on the Instance class so I prepared this:

```
forms.py
class InstanceComment(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Instance
        fields = '__all__'
```

I use the generic list view to display the list of Assets, when I click on one of them, I then display a list of the Instances attached to it using a Detail view. What I would like, is that on this page, have for each of the Instances, a form to edit the comment (there can be only one comment per Instance). I am struggling to see how to pass multiple forms to the view. I guess this is a very standard question with Django but I could not figure it out so far...

Could I get any guidance on this?

So far, I do not see how to effectively send a list of forms to the view. The view is based on the Asset model, while the comments forms are attached to Instances model, so I am stuck in here.

Comment: Instance was a bad choice for a model, it's kinda "reserved" word on django. It'd be like calling a model "Model"

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, that will save me some issues very soon I guess!

Answer (score 0):

When working with the generic CBV you need to think in terms of CRUD where one page equals one action. If you have a page where you display an Instance detail and you have a form to create a comment, then in terms of CRUD, that's not an InstanceDetailView, that's more a CommentCreateView, something like:

```
path('instance/<int:instance_id>/', views.year_archive),

class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = CommentCreateForm

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance_obj = Instance.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["instance_id"])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # when creating the Comment, we'll inject the Instance instance to the comment
        form.instance.instance = self.instance_obj
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # here you might want to check if there's already a comment for the instance 
        # so you can send something to the template to hide the create form. Or you can also remove the form from the context.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, this is very usefull!

Only issue is that in my model, I plan to have a page to show the details of an Asset, meaning this will display multiple instances (that's why I used a DetailView of Asset for that).
For each of the instances displayed, I want to be able to edit a comment attached. I guess it would be fairly easy from this page with multiple instances to have a link to open a detail view of my instance, and then display only one form, but I would love to be able to do that from the page where I see the multiples instances (thus multiples forms displayed)